# How MVC and CSD design pattern relate or differ from each other?

Tags: spring-mvc, design-patterns

I am working of SpringMVC architecture based which uses CSD design pattern. I am not able to understand as to which layer MVC is related with corresponding which layer of CSD. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC controller is a UI pattern, you can see some reference here
http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/modelViewController.html